# Make Ignore some of variable of the declared object when serializing to JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

may I know how to ignore some of member variables from the class that declared it. For example, below is the 3 classes, which is `PersonalInfo` and declared by `AcedemicInfo` and `FamilyInfo`.

```
public class PersonalInfo {
    @JsonPropetry
    private String name;

    @JsonPropetry
    String universityName;

    @JsonPropetry
    private String motherName;

    @JsonPropetry
    private String fatherName;

    /* Set and Get*/
}

public class AcademicInfo {
    @JsonPropetry
    private PersonalInfo info; // need name and university only

    /* Set and Get*/
}

public class FamilyInfo {
    @JsonPropetry
    private PersonalInfo info; // need name and fatherName and motherName only

    /* Set and Get*/
}
```

However, I need to ignore some of the member variables of `PersonalInfo` as the `AcedemicInfo` and `FamilyInfo` does not need all the attribute from `PersonalInfo`.

Below is my desired output

```
// Acedemic info json
{
    "info" : {
        "name":"Adam",
        "universityName":"University"
        }
}

// Family info json
{
    "info" : {
        "name":"Adam",
        "fatherName":"Matt"
        "motherName":"Jane"
        }
}
```

I know about `@JsonIgnore`, but if I put the annotation in the `PersonalInfo` class, the variable will be ignore by all the class that declare it, which is not what I want. May I know how to ignore the variable conditionally? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: did you try @JsonIgnore ?

Comment: @JsonIgnore should solve this for you

Comment: @Rustam, Yes, I tried that. But I have no idea how to apply it in my case. Can `@JsonIgnore` apply conditionally or depend on which class calling it?

Comment: @user3765370, Yes, I know `@JsonIgnore`, but how to apply it in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do is use `@JsonFilter` with `SimpleFilterProvider` and `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` to exclude properties not to serialize.

You class will look like follows:

```
public class AcademicInfo {
    @JsonFilter("academicPersonalInfoFilter")
    private PersonalInfo info; 
}
```

and the example to serialize the object:

```
SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
filterProvider.addFilter("academicPersonalInfoFilter",
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("motherName", "fatherName"));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setFilters(filterProvider);
mapper.writeValueAsString(academicInfo);
```

Another way to do is use multiple `@JsonView` to define a set of properties to serialize.

In you case, you can define views like follows:

```
public class Views {

    public static class BasicPersonalInfo {
    }

    public static class AcademicPersonalInfo extends BasicPersonalInfo  {
    }

    public static class FamilyPersonalInfo extends BasicPersonalInfo {
    }
}
```

and annotate the field to be serialized in the corresponding view:

```
public class PersonalInfo {
    @JsonView(Views.BasicPersonalInfo.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(Views.AcademicPersonalInfo.class)
    String universityName;

    @JsonView(Views.FamilyPersonalInfo.class)
    private String motherName;

    @JsonView(Views.FamilyPersonalInfo.class)
    private String fatherName;
}
```

and serialize object as follows:

```
String result = mapper.writerWithView(Views.AcademicPersonalInfo.class)
                      .writeValueAsString(academicInfo);
```

Comment: Thank for answering my question. However, I pass my `object` into `ResponseEntity.ok().body(object)`. May I know where can applied the `@JsonFilter` or `@JsonView`? Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: About `@JsonView`, you can have a look to https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Comment: Thanks for your link, now I am figure out how to do it in Spring. And also sorry about that I didn't mention Spring in my question. `@JsonView` support for serialization and deserialization which save my time to create less classes.